# Estou com problema em deixar essa div centralizada e responsive

Tags: html, css

Estou com problema em deixar essa div centralizada e responsive alguém poderiam e ajudar?

```css
.ml{
 text-align: center;
 color:#3A89AF;
}
.ml p{
 text-align: center;
 color:#000;
}
.ml a{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-decoration-line: none;
}
.ml a:hover{
 color:#fff;
}
.animate
{
 transition: all 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none; 
}

.blue
{
 background-color: #3498DB;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.platina
{
 background-color: #00FF6C;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #0CAA45;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #00FF6C;
}

.gold
{
 background-color: #E8FF00;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #A1AD21;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #D8FF00;
}

.prata
{
 background-color: #969696;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #787575;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #969696;
}
.bronze
{
 background-color: #986208;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #634514;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #986208;
 margin-right: 60px;
}


.action-button:active
{
 transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
 <div class="ml">
  <h2>Caso prefira o Mercado Livre</h2>
  <p>Trabalhamos com pagseguro e mercadolivre, caso você tenha interesse de comprar por mercado livre.</p>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Diamante</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate platina">Platina</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate gold">Gold</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate prata">Prata</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate bronze">Bronze</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta tirar o `float: left` do `.action-button` (senão elementos vão para a esquerda), tirar o `margin-right: 60px;` de `.bronze` (senão ele faz um espaçamento na lateral direita de 60 pixels e impede a centralização) e alterar o `margin` do `.action-button` para `margin: 5px;` (todas as margens iguais, neste caso, é importante não apenas na centralização mas para o igual espaçamento de um botão ao outro):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.ml{
 text-align: center;
 color:#3A89AF;
}
.ml p{
 text-align: center;
 color:#000;
}
.ml a{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-decoration-line: none;
}
.ml a:hover{
 color:#fff;
}
.animate
{
 transition: all 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 40px;
   margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none; 
   display: inline-block;
}

.blue
{
 background-color: #3498DB;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.platina
{
 background-color: #00FF6C;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #0CAA45;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #00FF6C;
}

.gold
{
 background-color: #E8FF00;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #A1AD21;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #D8FF00;
}

.prata
{
 background-color: #969696;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #787575;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #969696;
}
.bronze
{
 background-color: #986208;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #634514;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #986208;
}


.action-button:active
{
 transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="ml">
   <h2>Caso prefira o Mercado Livre</h2>
   <p>Trabalhamos com pagseguro e mercadolivre, caso você tenha interesse de comprar por mercado livre.</p>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Diamante</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate platina">Platina</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate gold">Gold</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate prata">Prata</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate bronze">Bronze</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na classe `.ml a` adicione os seguintes atributos:

```
display:inline-block;
float:none;
```

```css
.ml{
 text-align: center;
 color:#3A89AF;
  min-width:100%;
  margin:auto;

}
.ml p{
 text-align: center;
 color:#000;
}
.ml a{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-decoration-line: none;
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;

}
.ml a:hover{
 color:#fff;
}
.animate
{
 transition: all 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  float: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none; 
}

.blue
{
 background-color: #3498DB;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.platina
{
 background-color: #00FF6C;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #0CAA45;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #00FF6C;
}

.gold
{
 background-color: #E8FF00;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #A1AD21;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #D8FF00;
}

.prata
{
 background-color: #969696;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #787575;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #969696;
}
.bronze
{
 background-color: #986208;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #634514;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #986208;
 margin-right: 60px;
}


.action-button:active
{
 transform: translate(0px,5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="ml">
  <h2>Caso prefira o Mercado Livre</h2>
  <p>Trabalhamos com pagseguro e mercadolivre, caso você tenha interesse de comprar por mercado livre.</p>
    
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Diamante</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate platina">Platina</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate gold">Gold</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate prata">Prata</a>
   <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate bronze">Bronze</a>

</div>
```